# Animate a border around an element in css

Tags: css, css-animations

What would be the code for a webkit css animation that traces out the border around an element (say a div or a heading) from one corner, around the entire element ending up back at the original corner?

In layman's terms, if someone was drawing a rectangle by pencil in one single line around the element.

The effect must be permanent and not just occur when the user hovers over the element.

Comment: can you show us what have you tried? add your code here

Comment: Show us what you have tried, only then we can help you.?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```css
@keyframes pencil {
  0% {
   transition: border-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25s;
   border-color: #000 #fff #fff #fff;
   top:0%;
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
   transition: border-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25s;
   border-color: #fff #000 #fff #fff;
   top:0%;
    right: 100%;
  }
  50% {
   transition: border-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25s;
   border-color: #fff #fff #000 #fff;
   top:100%;
    right: 100%;
  }
  75% {
   transition: border-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25s;
   border-color: #fff #fff #fff #000;
   top:100%;
    right: 0%;
  }
  100% {
   transition: border-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25s;
   border-color: #fff #fff #fff #fff;
   top:0%;
    right: 0%;
  }
}

.pencil-border {
 border: 2px solid #fff;
  animation: pencil 2s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="pencil-border">
Test
</div>
```